# Json values into NSArray Parsing in IOS

Tags: ios

How to store this data in `NSArray`?

I'm getting **JSON** response in this format like this:

```
{
    1 = USA;
    4 = India;
}
```

I need to convert this into NSArray

Comment: How? It's an object (dictionary). You just want all values in an array? `[myDictionary allValues]`

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON is a string, get an `NSData` object first:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then turn it into an `NSDictionary` using the `NSJSONSerialization` class:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

Since you said you want an `NSArray`, do the following:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [jsonDict allValues];
```

Note that the order of the entries in the array is undefined, according to Apple's documentation. So if you need a particular order, you'll have to figure out a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is `JSON` dictionary, First you convert this to `NSDictionary` from `JSON`.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = //parse json using NSJSONSerilization
NSArray *array = [dictionary allValues];
```

`allValues` will return an array with all objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary =[jsonString JSONValue];
NSArray *array = [dictionary allValues];
NSLog(@"Array values = %@",array);
```